How to generate ts types in mutiple files with swagger-typescript-api and nest/swagger?
I use the npx swagger-typescript-api -p http://localhost:3000/swagger/json -o ./src/openapi -n index.ts --clean-output --no-client --module-name-index 1 --module-name-first-tag to generate types
But all the types are in a same file, How can I do to split types in different files, such as iam and administrator ?
Here is my nest/swagger ApiTag
@ApiTags('administrator')
@Controller('administrator/menu')
export class MenuController {

  @Permissions(Permission.create_administrator_menu)
  @Post()
  create(@Body() createMenuInput: CreateMenuInput) {
    return this.menuService.create(createMenuInput);
  }

  @ApiQuery({ name: 'searchMenuInput', type: SearchMenuInput })
  @ApiResponse({ type: SearchMenuOutput, isArray: true })
  @Get()
  findAll(@Query() searchMenuInput: SearchMenuInput) {
    return this.menuService.findAll(searchMenuInput);
  }
}


Here is my swagger json:

I ask the chatgpt, but it still can't help me
